# Kotlin based PanacheEntity throws runtime exception

Tags: quarkus

I've got issue with configuring properly PanacheEntity classes with kotlin. Here's my entity:

```
package rs.dodalovic.ordinacija.patients.db

import io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntity
import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = "pacijent", schema = "ordinacija")
class Patient(
    @field:Column(name = "BR") @field:Id @field:GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) var id: Int,
    @field:Column(name = "Ime") var name: String,
    @field:Column(name = "Prezime") var lastname: String,
    @field:Column(name = "ImeOca") var fatherName: String,
    @field:Column(name = "JMBG") var personalNumber: String,
    @field:Column(name = "DatumRodjenja") var dob: String,
    @field:Column(name = "Adresa") var address: String,
    @field:Column(name = "Telefon") var phone: String,
    @field:Column(name = "Notes") var notes: String
) : PanacheEntity() {
    companion object {
        fun findById(id: Int): Patient? {
            return find<Patient>("id", id).firstResult()
        }

        fun deleteById(id: String) {
            PanacheEntity.delete("id", id).also {
                println("Attempt to delete by id $id resulted in $it deleted rows")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I call `findById` method, I get the following exception:

```
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This method is normally automatically overridden in subclasses: did you forget to annotate your entity with @Entity?
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.runtime.JpaOperations.implementationInjectionMissing(JpaOperations.java:367)
        at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.PanacheEntityBase.find(PanacheEntityBase.java:115)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Github issue, the problem is essentially that the Kotlin compiler when generating an invokeStatic bytecode instruction is not using the entity as the target, but the PanacheEntity.

It looks something like:

```
invokestatic  #xy                 // Method io/quarkus/hibernate/orm/panache/PanacheEntity.find:(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lio/quarkus/hibernate/orm/panache/PanacheQuery;
```

whereas similar examples in Java have bytecode like this:

```
invokestatic  #xy                  // Method io/quarkus/hibernate/orm/panache/Fruit.find:(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Lio/quarkus/hibernate/orm/panache/PanacheQuery;
```

I also should mention that this happens when trying to call a static of method of the Entity from inside a companion object of the entity.

Comment: So um... what can we do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've found two ways around this.

**Option 1:** use `PanacheRepository`, e.g.

```kotlin
@Entity
class Patient: PanacheEntity() {
    // ...
}

@ApplicationScoped
class PatientRepository: PanacheRepository<Patient> {
    fun findById(id: Int) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Option 2:** use `PanacheCompanion`, e.g.

```kotlin
@Entity
class Patient: PanacheEntity() {
    companion object: PanacheCompanion<Patient> {
        fun findById(id: Int) {
            // ...
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately option 2 is not supported for Reactive yet: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/16785